# Pass min and max date from table to select query

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I needed to fill gaps between dates so i got this sql query:

```
select * from (
  SELECT null as ID, to_date('15/08/28', 'yy/mm/dd') + ROWNUM - 1 as DATE_OF_RATE, null as VALUE, null as CURRENCY_ID
  FROM dual
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= to_date('15/09/05', 'yy/mm/dd') - to_date('15/08/28', 'yy/mm/dd') + 1
) empCur
left join CURRENCY_RATE cr on TRUNC(empCur.DATE_OF_RATE) = (cr.DATE_OF_RATE)
AND cr.currency_id = 4;
```

[image]
Instead of hard coded dates above i need to pass min and max *date_of_rate* from *currency_rate* table. So i tried this, but i got diffrent result:

```
select * from (
  SELECT null as ID, (select min(date_of_rate) from currency_rate) + ROWNUM - 1 as DATE_OF_RATE, null as VALUE, null as CURRENCY_ID
  FROM dual
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (select max(date_of_rate) - min(date_of_rate) + 1 from currency_rate)
) empCur
left join CURRENCY_RATE cr on TRUNC(empCur.DATE_OF_RATE) = (cr.DATE_OF_RATE)
where cr.date_of_rate between to_date('15/08/28', 'yy/mm/dd') and to_date('15/09/05', 'yy/mm/dd')
AND cr.currency_id = 4;
```

[image]

As you can see this didn't fill the gaps between date ranges. Is it even possible what i'm trying to achieve?

Comment: In your second query, you're using a `WHERE` condition on the left-joined table `CURRENCY_RATE` thereby basically defeating the left join and turning it into an inner join. Replace `WHERE` with `and` and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is basically fine.  The problem is the `where` clause.  That condition should be on the *first* table:

```
select *
from (select  null as ID, (select min(date_of_rate) from currency_rate) + ROWNUM - 1 as DATE_OF_RATE, null as VALUE, null as CURRENCY_ID
      from dual
      connect by level <= (select max(date_of_rate) - min(date_of_rate) + 1 from currency_rate)
     ) empCur left join
     CURRENCY_RATE cr
     on empCur.DATE_OF_RATE = cr.DATE_OF_RATE and
        cr.currency_id = 4
where empCur.DATE_OF_RATE >= date '2015-08-28' and
      empCur.DATE_OF_RATE <= date '2015-09-05' ;
```

I don't see why `TRUNC()` is necessary.  If it is, just add it back in.

Comment: Let's say my column date_of_rate is in the range from 2010-01-01 to 2018-01-01. Is it possible to get only the rows with date between 2015-08-28 and 2015-09-05? When i execute your query then i get rows with nulls everywhere from 2010-01-01 to 2015-08-27 and later from 2015-09-06 to 2018-01-01. My goal was to query date ranges without the gaps between the dates so i thought that first of all i will need to fill the gaps in whole table and then i will be able to query  only this rows that are between specified date range.

Ok after edit now i see it works exactly how i wanted! :)

Answer (score 0):

I find using temp variables can help. Here's what I would do. Please note my syntax is probably shakey as I'm doing this from memory. Some light googling will get you the rest of the way though.

Step 1. Create some temp variables. These need to get run in one command.

```
DECLARE @MinDate DATETIME;
DECLARE @MaxDate DATETIME;

@MinDate = SELECT Min([DATE_OF_RATE]) FROM CURRENCY_RATE; 
@MaxDate = SELECT Max([DATE_OF_RATE]) FROM CURRENCY_RATE;
```

Step 2. Create a calendar table of all possible dates, with literally date as the only column. Do this manually if you need to. You can always create a calendar table with days up to 2050, well after this system will no longer be in use.

Step 3. Do the left join from the calendar table to the rates table on the date. This will give you a row regardless of gaps in the rates.

```
SELECT c.CalDate FROM Calendar c
LEFT JOIN CURRENCY_RATE cr
ON c.CalDate = cr.DATE_OF_RATE
```

Step 4. Filter the new table where the date is in the min/max range using temp table

```
SELECT c.CalDate FROM Calendar c
LEFT JOIN CURRENCY_RATE cr
ON c.CalDate = cr.DATE_OF_RATE
WHERE c.CalDate >= @MinDate AND c.CalDate <= @MaxDate
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: That is not valid for Oracle